# Customizing OTP Authentication flow with AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I've currently integrated an OTP authentication signin flow to a React Native app with Amplify. The flow is as follows.

(I followed the guide provided in this [article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/building-otp-authentication-with-reactjs-and-aws-amplify-c5fd2e517fac))

[image]

But right now I'm in the need of providing the option of sending the OTP code to a user entered email address in case if it is not received to the mobile number.

Initial thought was to trigger the `create auth challenge` lambda function via Amplify `Auth.signUp` by sending `email` attribute.

```js
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';

const sendVerificationToEmail = async (phone: number, email: string, password: string) => {
  await Auth.signUp({ 
      username: phone, 
      password, 
      attributes: { 
         email 
      } });
}
```

Then the lambda function can be remodified as follows to either send an email or SMS,

```js
...

const email = event.request.userAttributes.email;

if (email) {
  // Logic to send OTP verification code via SES
} else {
  // Logic to send OTP via SNS
}
```

but this is not possible since we already have a user created in the cognito user pool. This attribute will not be passed to the lambda function.

What is the correct approach of achieving this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest approach is, Setup lambda function for custom flow.

1. Create custom method to generate an OTP and save it to into a table and
   then use SES to send OTP to email .
2. Create custom method to verify OTP.
3. Check OTP from table and verify it.

> ```
>  if(SUCCESS)
>         use admin to mark as verified
> ```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminConfirmSignUp.html

Comment: IMHO this is not a good approach.
In current implementation we are not getting a database involved to persist OTP codes.

Comment: You can use twilio to send and verify OTP  then. @PasinduDilshan